# Compile and Run a string of C source code

Tags: c, gcc

So, I want to compile and run a string of C source code, where the string is a `const char*` and represents an entire program. It should be taken from either a constant or constructed string, such as

```
const char* prog = "#include <stdio.h> int main(void) {puts(\"foo\"); return 0;}"
```

I have already tried [tcclib](https://bellard.org/tcc/tcc-doc.html), but it currently doesn't build on Mac OS and due to lack of a consistent maintainer I don't think it's a viable way to do this.

I am mainly asking about this as a means to have a backend for a programming language that compiles to C. If there is some library function in `gcc` or `clang`, that would work too.

Note: This is specifically about compiling C code from C, not injecting it into a process.

Comment: Why not just write the string to a file and call a compiler?

Comment: why you do not write that string in a file then ask to compile it then run the exe ? Where s the problem if you have gcc installed ?

Comment: I'm almost sure I have seen this question (or very similar) asked before, but the one that is currently marked as duplicate does not seem to be it. This question is about compiling C code from C code, not about taking a string of code and injecting it into a process.

Comment: @bruno My idea was not having to deal with different windows and unix path names (windows utf-16 pathnames). But perhaps just calling gcc is a preferable solution.

Comment: So in principle there is an experimental programmatic interface to GCC, [libgccjit](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/jit/), and LLVM was designed to be much more accessible in this sense, you may be able to find more information googling for "use clang/llvm as a library" (like [this now unmaintained repository](https://github.com/eliben/llvm-clang-samples)).

Comment: You could take a look at [cling](https://cdn.rawgit.com/root-project/cling/master/www/index.html), which can be embedded. In theory, I guess, you could do all that with libclang and LLVM, which might turn out to be a good learning experience but is likely to be a lot more complicated than tcc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> @bruno My idea was not having to deal with different windows and unix path names (windows utf-16 pathnames). But perhaps just calling gcc is a preferable solution.

I think calling GCC is easiest. However, just because you're calling GCC as an external process, doesn't mean you have to write your generated C to a file.

GCC is capable of taking its output from standard in. Here's an example, written in Bash.

```
echo "main(){}" | gcc -x c -
```

Here's the same thing in C:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

const char *prog = "#include <stdio.h>\nint main(void) {puts(\"foo\"); return 0;}";

int main() {
    FILE *proc = popen("gcc -x c -", "w");
    fwrite(prog, sizeof(char), strlen(prog), proc);
    pclose(proc);
}
```

And here's the same thing, but with error handling:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

const char *prog = "#include <stdio.h>\nint main(void) {puts(\"foo\"); return 0;}";

int main() {
    FILE *proc = popen("gcc -x c -", "w");
    if(!proc) {
        perror("popen gcc");
    }
    fwrite(prog, sizeof(char), strlen(prog), proc);
    if(ferror(proc)) {
        perror("writing prog");
    }
    if(pclose(proc) == -1) {
        perror("pclose gcc");
    }
}
```

I think that's the best way of accomplishing this.